# How to retrieve more than 5000 records from DYNAMICS 365 CE/CRM using Azure Data Factory via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamics-crm, etl

How to retrieve more than 5000 records from DYNAMICS 365 CE/CRM using Azure Data Factory via REST API?

In Azure Data Factory, I have configured the pagination rule as below but does not work.

[image]

Comment: can you add error you are facing for more understanding?